# 3 criteria for an if statement excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

How can I add a third set of criteria to an if statement. There are 3 vaules: Pass, Fail or ND. My code will read the cell and assign it to a pass or fail.

`=IF(OR(A1 = "Fail",A2 = "Fail", A3 = "Fail"), "Fail", "Pass")`

However if the cell contains an ND how can record this? 
I was thinking something like below, but that doesn’t work.

```
=IF(OR(A1 = "Fail",A2 = "Fail", A3 = "Fail", A4 = “ND”), "Fail", "Pass", “ND”)
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "how can record this".

Comment: You now got 4 parameters whereas you can only have `IF(<your test>,<what if TRUE>,<what if FALSE>)`. What exactly are you trying here?

Comment: Do you mean something like that? `=IF(OR(A1 = "Fail",A2 = "Fail", A3 = "Fail"), "Fail", IF(A4="ND","ND","Pass"))`

Comment: @JustynaMK "There are 3 vaules: Pass, Fail or ND", so I don't think it can be handled that easily. I suspect A1 can also be `ND`.

Comment: Thanks @Jerry, agreed it wasn't totally clear. OP just accepted the answer where only `A4` can be `ND` so I was a little bit too late. Oh well :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following formula.

```
=IF(A4="ND","ND",IF(OR(A1 = "Fail",A2 = "Fail", A3 = "Fail"), "Fail", "Pass"))
```